# Is it necessary to escape the replacement string in a String.replace() call with a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

In wonder if it is necessary to escape certain chars in the replacement string of a replace operation in Javascript. What I have is this:

```
let t = "##links##";
let t2 = t.replace(/##links##/, `{"labels": ["'$'"]}`);
console.log(t2);
```

The console output is:

```
{"labels": ["'"]}
```

which is pretty surprising. However, I cannot find anything in the documentation that suggests to escape the replacement string. So, what's going on here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the `$` symbol to replace with a literal `$`:

```js
let t = "##links##";
let t2 = t.replace(/##links##/, `{"labels": ["'$$'"]}`);
console.log(t2);
```

See [Specifying a string as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) listing all the possible "special" combinations inside a regex replacement part.

If you check that table, you will see that `$` starts the "special" sequences. Thus, it should be escaped in some way. In JS, a dollar is used to escape the literal dollar symbol. `$&` is a backreference to the whole match, `` $` `` inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring, `$'`    inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring. `$n`  is a backrefernece to Group *n*.

So, if you have a dynamic, user-defined replacement string that is not supposed to have backreferences, you may use

```js
let t = "##links##";
let  rep = `{"labels": ["'$'"]}`;
let t2 = t.replace(/##links##/, rep.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$'));
console.log(t2);
```

Comment: Can you explain why? Is the replacement string processed in any way? Is there something online which describe what needs to be considered for the replacement content?

Comment: The only char you need to take care of is `$` actually. Once you escape it with another `$`, the replacement will be treated as a literal string.

Comment: Who knows why the casual downvoter votes as he does? Both our answers were down voted around the same time. Here is a plus one _por vous_.

Answer (score 1):

Dollar sign (`$`) is special in [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). If you want a single, literal dollar sign, use `$$`. Otherwise, [*the replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

> - `$$` Inserts a `$`.
> - `$&` Inserts the matched substring.
> - `` $` `` Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched    substring.
> - `$'` Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched    substring.
> - `$n` Where `n` is a positive integer less than 100, inserts the `n`th    parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument
>     was a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object.